# Run scrapy crawl using cron

Tags: cron, scrapy

I have been trying to run my crawler using cron but nothing happens and the csv file that my crawler generates does not get updated. In short nothing happens. Here is my below code.
My scrapy project path:

```
root or home directory/insider/insider/spiders --> This folder contains the insider.py file i.e crawler script.
```

example.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd/root/insider
PATH =$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
scrapy crawl insider
```

crontab file

```
*/2 * * * * cd /root && example.sh
```

Comment: In the `example.sh` file is `cd/root/insider` a typo here or do you really miss the blank between `cd` and the path?

Comment: That was a typo here..